# How can I morph an object into a liquid and back to a different object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, physics, fluid-simulation

I suppose I found nothing about because I don't know the proper technique name/terminology.

I'm working in my first videogame, an adventure-suspense walking simulator. I need to know techniques/tools/modifiers/plugins names about the next example.

I have a genetically modified character who can transform into a liquid, and reverse, the sequence it's he has one single hair of himself, drop it in a table, then the hair transforms into a grey liquid drop, and the drop transforms progressively into a flower.

I need that technique in reverse as well, to transform some liquids coming from different places progressively into the characters body.

Can someone give me an approximation about what I need to know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Morphing maybe?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphing

Comment: Searching about morphing I only get results about images/pictures. Talking into Blender language I just found this technique requires various processes, which one of the may be building modifier but that just makes the mesh composition/transition movement. So the drop to flower models transition may need something more, the textures and meshes geometry as well....

Comment: Cegaton, actually what I need it's terminology for the processes involved in that technique but thanks for the edit anyway.

Comment: I think you may want to look into [Blender Fluid Dissolve](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+dissolve+fluid&tbm=vid) animations, though I couldn't really find much about the reverse effect. I'm gonna go out on a limb and say those are possible just animations played in reverse, though in your case that might not work. This is just theory, but maybe use an object with an attraction force to make the fluid stick back to it?

Comment: Sorry about that, if you feel my edit changed the meanig of the words just rever it back, but please avoid long walls of text, use proper paragraphs for better readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the terminology you want is "Fluid Control".  If you google "Blender Fluid Control", you will find some tutorials on YouTube that will make fluid crawl up onto a shape (Suzanne for instance).  Then I think the compositor is your friend.